# Prevent AutoNumber Reset During Compact/Repair (MS Access)

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

Is it possible, during compact/repair of an Access database, to prevent the AutoNumber ID from resetting?

For example, if I have records 1-10 and I delete record 10, then compact/repair, 10 will be the next record.  What I'd like is for 11 to be the next record.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have to ask: why? If there is *anything* still pointing to record 10, you shouldn't have been able to delete it. And if not, it shouldn't matter at all that a new record will have ID 10.

Comment: I believe the answer is No. As @Andre asks, why should it matter?

Comment: I setup the database (programmatically) to delete a record from one table and insert it into another table.  The problem shows up when I compact and repair because now there are 'unused' numbers that get reset.  If I was to move record 10 from one table to another, and then compact and repair, record 10 becomes available in the first table.  Now when I try to move the new record 10 to the second table, it faults because I cannot have two record 10's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An autonumber is only for *identifying* the record and should not be meaningful.

If 10 and 11 and so on means something for your application and/or the user, have a separate field to hold these numbers.

Comment: Thanks - this was a short-sided move on my part.